# Redis running version unmatch actual version

Tags: redis, installation, development-environment

Ubuntu 18.04

My Redis-Server Version:

`Redis server v=5.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=71f661bb00c4db91`

My Redis-Cli Version:

`redis-cli 5.0.5`

However, my redis is running on 4.0.9, so please let me know how can I change the configure and make my redis running on 5.0. Thank you.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Server
redis_version:4.0.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there are two versions of Redis-server in my environment, and after uninstalling the unmatched running version, it works properly.